# JQuery get the option of a checkbox checked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm doing some code where i need to get the option(value) from an checkbox checked

Here is how i create the checkbox

```
function createCheckbox(txt) {  
 var comb = document.createElement("Select");
 comb.className = "something";
 for (var i = 0; i < txt.length; i++) {
    var option = document.createElement("OPTION");
    var optionText = document.createTextNode(txt[i]); //some options
    option.appendChild(optionText);
    comb.appendChild(option);
 }
 return comb;
}
```

Function where i need to show the option that is selected

```
function foo{
     var inputTextValue = document.getElementsByClassName("something");
      var checkedValue = $(inputTextValue).is(':checked');
      alert(checkedValue);   //true/false
}
```

the alert only show true /false depeding if the checkbox is checked or not.But what i need its the option checked. I already tried $(inputTextValue).is(':checked').val().

Comment: When you create elements, try to be consistent, and use lowercase letters. Also, you're returning the select, but where does it end up, and what does it have to do with a checkbox ?

Comment: i just put here the way i create the checkbox to show if there was any error on the creation (i think the functio its okay) ... but the functions are separated  .. i just need somet jquery function to retrive the value if the checkbox is selected. And i was used to java and their camel case

Comment: checkbox != select. You say you're creating a checkbox but you aren't, you're creating a select (dropdown list). Therefore testing whether it's checked doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkbox and Select are two different HTML Elements

For Getting the value of Selected option use

```
$(".something option:selected").val();
```

Answer (score 1):

I think tou mix here between checkbox and select.
Select option is selected with :selected attribute.
Checkbox is checked with :checked attribute.

Answer (score 0):

The value of a `<select>` is the value of the selected option.

```
$(".something").val()
```